# Alphabetical lists in Russian?

Tags: буквы, алфавит

In English, I might make a list of things like so:

```
A. This is the first item!
B. This is the second item!
C. You guessed it! Third item!
```

In Russian, is that done the same way? i.e.:

```
а. Первый элемент
б. Второй элемент
в. ...
г. ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Russian. However, the letters Ё, Й, Ъ, Ы and Ь [are usually omitted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation#Labeling_of_ordered_items).

Comment: But why are Ё, Й and Ы omitted?

Comment: @Catbuntu My best guess is that the reasons for "Ё" and "Й" are different from the reasons for "Ы": the "Ё" and "Й" look too similar to "Е" and "И", so they are not used to avoid confusion. "Ы", on the other hand, is very unusual at the start of any word (there's only a handful of words starting in "Ы", and these are mostly borrowed from East Asian languages), so "Ы" is therefore not suitable for being used as a header list bullet.